# What is the icon or logo that represent UNIX?

Tags: unix

Hello fellow root users ...

Windows, Mac, Linux ... all have a windows/logo/icon to represent each. What do you think would be a appropriate icon/image/logo to represent "UNIX" in general? (I know UNIX has different flavors .... but just wondering if there is one that represent the general UNIX family)

Comment: Seems like a SuperUser question if anything

Answer (score 8):

It is a registered trademark visible at: http://www.unix.org/

It's just UNIX in all caps, and sometimes small caps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general "UNIX" logo or icon, but take a look at [this](http://www.unix.org/u30logo.html) website.

Comment: Lol many of those logos are horrible beyond belief.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use #! and everyone would probably get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by *n*x, with that I mean all Linux variates, 'real' (that is posix certified) unix systems and unix derived systems like *BSD's. But it does seem that I am the only one doing that and always have to explain what it means :-)

Comment: It actually should be `*n?x` ;)))

Comment: Yeah, assuming the reader knows regex :-) But for simple minds like me, * is interpreted like any possible character(s).

Comment: I've always seen *nix used, including even Linux despite not being strictly correct. This is the first time I see this.